# Acumatica Customization - How to remove anonymous delegate from PXGraph.RowInsertingEvents Collection?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I‘m working on customization that involves adding extra Sales Person transactions when Cancelling/Correcting an Invoice. As part of the development effort, I have identified that the common method that’s called by both the processes – Cancel Invoice and Correct Invoice, is `ReverseDocumentAndApplyToReversalIfNeeded` in the Graph `PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceEntry`.

I have the custom code to add new salespersons to the `ARInvoiceEntry.salesPerTrans` view but when I do after `ReverseDocumentAndApplyToReversalIfNeeded` runs, I see that my code doesn’t insert the new records to the view and doesn’t give any error. After much troubleshooting, I’ve found out that there’s a line of code in the method `ReverseInvoiceProc` of ARInvoiceEntry.cs that stops from inserting a new row. Here’s that line of code:

```
this.RowInserting.AddHandler<ARSalesPerTran>((sender, e) => { e.Cancel = true; });
```

It’s an anonymous delegate that’s added.

I would like to know how can I get hold of this anonymous handler in my custom code so that I can:

1. Remove that anonymous handler
2. Do my custom logic of adding new rows
3. Add the anonymous delegate back to the `RowInsertingEvents` list

I tried to look in the Acumatica code repository but couldn’t find anything that would help me remove anonymous delegate. What I can find was the removal of named handlers, like the below example:

```
APPaymentEntry pe = CreateInstance<APPaymentEntry>();
pe.RowSelecting.RemoveHandler<APPayment>(pe.APPayment_RowSelecting);
```

So please let me know how can I dynamically remove that anonymous handler from within my custom code. I have reference to the ARInvoiceEntry graph through the Base property of my extension graph. If you can redirect me to a specific page in the Acumatica Code repository, that would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you could remove this anonymous method from there in a easy way.

However, one approach you could implement is to override the "ReverseDocumentAndApplyToReversalIfNeeded" method and call base method there.

After this you could create a new instance of the ARinvoiceEntry graph (in that same override after calling base method), select the primary record(header) and then try to make your second insert ( this way to avoid the ReverseInvoiceProc.)